# Why does Type.Equals() always returns false with generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have this class:

```
public abstract class GenericType<T> { ... }
```

It has several deriving classes. When I take a derived object and do this:

```
GenericType<Parameter> someObject = GetObject(); // details omitted
if (someObject.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GenericType<>))) { ... }
```

The if block never executes because the expression is always false.

I wrote this function to try and work around the issue:

```
private bool IsDesiredType(Type type) {
    while (type.BaseType != null) {
        Type desiredType = typeof(GenericType<>);
        if (type.BaseType.IsEquivalentTo(desiredType)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This failed as well and when debugging it, I observed that the IsEquivalentTo function always returns false, even if they're actually representing the same type. The same applies to Equals. I noticed that the string representation of `typeof(GenericType<>)` does not include information about the assembly, while the type stored in a variable does have this information.

[image: DebuggerDisplay of typeof() expression. Does not contain assembly information.]

[image: DebuggerDisplay of variable. Contains assembly information.]

The [documentation confirms this but does not explain why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.equals?view=netframework-4.8), or what I could do instead. (See below 2nd example)

How should I check if two Type objects representing a generic type are equal?

Comment: Instead of focusing on what your code *doesn't do*, could you tell us what your code *is supposed to do*? This would make it easier to tell you how to (re)write your code.

Comment: If you mean "inherits from `GenericType<>`" then that doesn't work because generics doesn't do that. You could check if the type is a generic type where the generic definition is `GenericType<>` or if any of its base types is one like that, but then you have to write the code to actually do that, but I'm not sure what you actually want done here and why so it's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Well `GenericType<Foo>` and `GenericType<Bar>` are completely different types, so why would `GenericType<>` be a match? I suspect you want to use `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericType<>)`?

Comment: ~~ I want it to return true in the situation displayed in the image, I thought that was clear enough.~~  Ninja'd by 3 comments.

Comment: Ok, create an extension method with `return true;` then. As I said, in order to help you (re)write your code, we need to know **why** you want it to return `true`.

Comment: See if DavidG's comment is what you're after, this seems most likely.

Comment: @Magnetron this has solved my problem, this question can be marked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As your `GenericType<T>` is declared abstract, I'm assuming that you've declared some derived classes and these are what you instantiate:

```
// GetObject presumably creates an instance of a class that inherits GenericType<Parameter>
GenericType<Parameter> someObject = GetObject();
```

In this case, calling `GetType()` on `someObject` will return the type of the derived class, not the `GenericType<>`.

In order to ascertain whether `someObject` inherits from `GenericType<>` you need to get the base type:

```
if (someObject.GetType().BaseType ...)
```

However, as you actually want to establish if the type is assignable from the generic type, you should then obtain the type definition of the generic type from the base type using `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`:

```
if (someObject.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GenericType<>)))
```

This will return true in the case of `someObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the assignable from as

```
if (someObject.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GenericType<>))) { ... }
```